# Button inside button MVVM. How to hit the inner button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a **'plus'** button (see image) inside big button. How execute command of 'plus' button.
'plus' button in my example is **CreateNewFolderButton**(first style) and locate in **Grid.Column**=2 of **MakeNewFolderButton**(second style).

---

Tinkering with **WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome** and **IsHitTestVisible** doesn't help.
How to get access to the **'plus'** button and execute its command with MVVM?

```
<Style x:Key="CreateNewFolderButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource HoverLess}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Create Folder"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Grid >
                    <Ellipse Width="{StaticResource WidthNavigationAndCreation}" Height="{StaticResource HeightNavigationAndCreation}" />
                    <Ellipse Width="{StaticResource WidthNavigationAndCreation}" Height="{StaticResource HeightNavigationAndCreation}" x:Name="image" >
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="{DynamicResource AddFolder}" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"  TargetName="image" Value="{DynamicResource IBAddFolderMouseOver}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MakeNewFolderButton"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource FolderFileButtons}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0 0 0 0.5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Width="{StaticResource WidthFolderAndFilesIcon}"
                               Height="{StaticResource HeightFolderAndFilesIcon}" Source="/Images/FolderAndFiles/BlackEmptyFolder48x48.png"/>                            
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxEnterFileCreation}"
                                 Tag="New Folder Name"
                                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                                        Path=DataContext.NewFolderName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource CreateNewFolderButton}"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.MakeFolder}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundMouseOver}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

['Plus' button inside big button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWApV.jpg)

Comment: I think your problem begins with placing a button inside another button. Why does MakeNewFolderButton need to be a button in the first place?

Comment: What is the requirement for the outer button? it seems to be two buttons and a text field from your image so why not wrap them in a layout instead?

Comment: @whiskeycoder because in further i want to change style of another buttons to this style.

Comment: Ok but I have the same question as @Corcus why does the outer button need to be a button and not a layout. What action does the outer button click do? if it does not do anything I would advise you change it to a layout, however, I'm conscious I don't know the full use case

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Command binding for button and button in it works. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rekshino I can’t post an MCVE now. Can you show your solution? Because in my case a big button just like overlapping inner button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment this code works:

```
<Button Content="Outer button" Command="{Binding TestCmd}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="LABEL CONTENT" Foreground="BlueViolet"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="INNER BUTTON" Command="{Binding TestCmd2}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

So if you press "INNER BUTTON" the `TestCmd2` being executed and if you click a "LABEL CONTENT" the `TestCmd` being executed.

Comment: False alarm. I assign to textbox.lostkeyboardfocus a method, which hide this whole button. That why it doesn't work. I am dumb